# In the AWS codePipeline , while the script is running in the log , its showing the following error . fix this

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-ec2, aws-codepipeline

**this is the buildspec.yml:**

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - npm install -g typescript
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Installing source NPM dependencies...
      - npm install
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - npm run build
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
artifacts:
  files:
    - public/**/*
    - package.json
    - package-lock.json
    - node_modules/**/*
    - swagger.yaml
    - appspec.yaml
```

**this is the tsconfig.json:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */
    /* Basic Options */
    // "incremental": true,                         /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "target": "es6" /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', 'ES2021', or 'ESNEXT'. */,
    "module": "commonjs" /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */,
    "lib": [
      "DOM",
      "ES2017"
    ] /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */,
    // "allowJs": true,                             /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                             /* Report errors in .js files. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                           /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', 'react', 'react-jsx' or 'react-jsxdev'. */
    // "declaration": true,                         /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                      /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                           /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                             /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    "outDir": "public" /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */,
    "rootDir": "src" /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */,
    // "composite": true,                           /* Enable project compilation */
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./",                     /* Specify file to store incremental compilation information */
    // "removeComments": true,                      /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    // "noEmit": true,                              /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                       /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,                  /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,                     /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */
    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
    // "noImplicitAny": true,                       /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,                    /* Enable strict null checks. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,                 /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,                 /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,        /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                      /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                        /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */
    /* Additional Checks */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                      /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,                  /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,                   /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,          /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */
    // "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,            /* Include 'undefined' in index signature results */
    // "noImplicitOverride": true,                  /* Ensure overriding members in derived classes are marked with an 'override' modifier. */
    // "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,  /* Require undeclared properties from index signatures to use element accesses. */
    /* Module Resolution Options */
    // "moduleResolution": "node",                  /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                             /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                                 /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                              /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                             /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                                 /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,        /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */,
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,                    /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */
    // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,                /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */
    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                            /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                               /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,                     /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                       /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */
    /* Experimental Options */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,              /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,               /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
    /* Advanced Options */
    "skipLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  }
}
```

**in the AWS codePipeline , while the script is running in the log , its showing the following error . how to fix this :**

```
> justpoll-server@1.0.0 build
> tsc -p .

error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'cron'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Entry point for implicit type library 'cron'

[Container] 2023/09/06 11:49:49 Command did not exit successfully npm run build exit status 2
[Container] 2023/09/06 11:49:49 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2023/09/06 11:49:49 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: npm run build. Reason: exit status 2
[Container] 2023/09/06 11:49:49 Entering phase POST_BUILD
[Container] 2023/09/06 11:49:49 Running command echo Build completed on `date`
Build completed on Wed Sep 6 11:49:49 UTC 2023
```

I am encountering an error during the build phase of their AWS CodePipeline, which is part of their software development and deployment process. The error message they provided is related to TypeScript, a programming language that adds static typing to JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

1. Uninstall schedule:

```bash
npm uninstall @nestjs/schedule
```

2. Remove directory `node_modules`
3. Remove the file `package.lock.json`
4. Install modules:

```bash
npm install
```

3. Install schedule:

```bash
npm install --save @nestjs/schedule
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue because @nest/schedule dependency (requires cron) was not getting updated. Check your package.json file

```
"@nestjs/schedule": "ˆ2.1.0",
"@nestjs/schedule": "^2.1.0",
```